# Screen Glitches in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: ssms

I recently downloaded SQL Server Management Studio Version 18.4 on Windows 10.

I don't know if I just got a buggy installer or what. It opens up fine, I can log in to the server just fine. Then as I'm typing and executing queries, the page will start doing some wonky things. Colorful stripes will appear inside the text field. The icons at the top of the page will disappear and reappear. Lines like notebook lines will appear to the right of the queries I'm typing, and sometimes even the text I'm typing will disappear.

It's not getting deleted, the text will literally just turn white or something so I can't see it until I minimize and reopen the page. Has anybody else had any issues like this?

The screenshot below has queries typed in it. You just can't see them:

[image]

Comment: Try restarting the system once.If that doesn't help, uninstall and reinstall the ssms.

Comment: is this SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)? Or the console client? Or what? Your screenshot shows you're using SSMS, so luckily it's obvious to us, but in future you should make it 100% clear what you're using. And...don't confuse the server where the queries are executed with the client software where you type them. There are many possible clients for SQL Server. And this is far more likely to be the source of the fault than SQL Server itself, which is a separate piece of software running in the background. I've edited your question to use more accurate terminology.

Answer (score 4):

The GUI client that is installed with SQL Server is called "SQL Server Management Studio" or SSMS. Searching for "SSMS display problems" yields some promising results, such as https://sqlserver.pro/how-to-fix-sql-server-management-studio-graphics-problem

The point here is to disable **Hardware Graphics Acceleration** which can be found in Tools -> Options -> General section.

Here you need to **uncheck** following checkboxes:

- Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance
- Enable rich client visual experience
- Use hardware graphics acceleration if available